# Virtual function replaced by a non-virtual one

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

Today I have found something which really surprised me:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void reset() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void reset() override {
        cout << "reset()";
    }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    void reset(int r) {
        cout << "reset(" << r << ")";
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.reset();
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile the code as is, the compiler complains about `reset()` not matched. However if I comment `reset(int r)` out, `reset()` is miraculously found. How is this possible? There isn't a signature conflict or whatever so why is this happening?

Comment: When I turn on warnings, the compiler tells me that `C::reset` hides `B::reset` because it has a different signature.  You should turn on warnings.

Comment: This is called "name hiding" and there are loads of explanations on StackOverflow and elsewhere.

Comment: @Eljay at least my g++ 8.1 -Wall -std=gnu++11 doesn't emit any warnings.

Comment: Ironically, GCC `-Wall` does not include all the warnings.  Add `-Woverloaded-virtual`.